# How to replace double quotes in Erlang

Tags: erlang

This is probably a rather trivial question for the Erlang experts - I'm trying to have my ejabberd server store offline messages (in a Riak db) which inherently do contain double quotes (`"`) around various values, etc. I get a format error when I try to create a Riak database object from them, and testing of replacing the double quotes with an escape character (`\"`) corrects the issue. The question is how can I do this replacement manually?

I tried the following code but somehow doesn't work.

```
(ejabberd@xxx-xx-xx-xxx)4> re:replace(""hello"", """, "\"", [{return, list}, global]).    
* 1: syntax error before: hello
```

So essentially I'm trying to replace the embedded `"` around the hello word with `\"`.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know Erlang, but you probably need something like this:

```
"\"hello\"", "\"", "\\\""
```

Comment: Thanks but the catch is that the hello string is the source, so I cannot modify it and put the backslashes.

Comment: I thought so (and that this was a test), just replace `""hello""` with the variable (to the source).

Comment: @vikram17000, then need complete example. Look this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130681/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-erlang

Comment: Thanks @Danny_ds  ... I've put in further comments below as to how this still wouldnt work... appreciate if you'd have further color...

Comment: @vikram17000 - Quick question: does your original value have 1 or 2 double quotes on each side? i.e. `""hello""` or `"hello"`.

Comment: Hey @Danny_ds - actually the string is rather complicated... here it is... so multiple double quotes inside this string which is in a var. What I want to do is change this var so that the new var contains backslashed double quotes everywhere.... `{xmlel,<<"message">>,[{<<"type">>,<<"chat">>},{<<"id">>,<<"purplefe7f4130">>},{<<"to">>,<<"myuser@xx.xx.xx.xx">>}],[{xmlel,<<"active">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates">>}],[]},{xmlel,<<"body">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"dfd">>}]}]}`

Comment: Yeah somehow it doesnt... gives a badarg error for re:replace ... splitting my hair :-(

Comment: So if I store this string as is in a var and manually put a \ ahead of every ", and then run the re:replace command, it works perfectly. But if I pass the original string to the said command, it doesnt...

Comment: @vikram17000 - And if you try with a constant var first, like you did first - `"\"hello\"", "\"", "\\\""`? There might be another problem too. Would love to help with other, but as I said, I don't know Erlang - but escaping chars should be simple on a normal day.

Comment: @vikram17000 - Yes, must be that 'other' problem then. Problem with conversion of the list maybe. Perhaps try with a smaller one first?

Comment: Thanks @Danny_ds ... yes smaller strings work fine. Thanks anyways - believe I've got to figure out the internals of Erlang further...

Comment: @vikram17000 - Almost there then. Gradually add some data until you reach the point of error. Good luck!

Comment: @vikram17000 - Got something strange here looking at your data - some special chars (could be normal, I don't know): `{??<<"to">>,` - `<<"http://??jabber.` - `<<"dfd">>??}]}]}` -- check the `??` - those are not visible in your comment. (but could as well be pasted newlines or something)

Comment: Ooops @Danny_ds ... my bad and apologies for leading you the wrong way... I actually meant "smaller strings also don't work" ...! Is definitely then somehting to do with how Erlang is functioning here... Thanks anyways for your help and inputs! I'll get back here the moment I figure out a solution!

Answer (score 2):

You must escape both `"` and `\` in replacement string.

> The Erlang literal syntax for strings uses the "\" (backslash)
>   character as an escape code. You need to escape backslashes in literal
>   strings, both in your code and in the shell, with an additional
>   backslash, i.e.: "\".

---

**Example:**

Let's make an example. I use `$` Erlang symbol which will be substituted with ascii integer of a character to show what is happening behind each string which basically is a list of integer.

```
Subject = [$"] ++ "hello" ++ [$"] = "\"hello\"".
Target = [$"] = "\"".
Replacement = [$\\, $\\, $"] = "\\\\\"".
Result = re:replace(Subject, Target, Replacement, [{return, list}, global]).
```

Now with getting the length of `Subject` and `Result` we can find the difference:

```
7 = length(Subject). %% => 7 characters: " h e l l o "
9 = length(Result). %% => 9 characters: \ " h e l l o \ "
```

Comment: Thanks @Hamidreza ... that was very helpful and educative - thanks for taking out the time.

Comment: That said, I still cant get the " to be replaced by \". Essentially, I'm trying to modify an ejabberd packet so that I can store it as a string on Riak. If I print the From variable using INFO_MSG, I get the value (for illustration) {jid,<<"myuser1">>}... how do I modify this From variable to replace the " with \". Clearly, running `NewFrom = re:replace(From, "\"", "\\\"", [{return, list}, global]),` just gives an error.

Comment: @vikram17000 First please make sure that in `re:replace(From, "\"", "\\\"", [{return, list}, global])` expression, `From` variable is a *List* or *Binary*, not a tuple of `{jid, <<"something">>}`. Then please use `re:replace(From, "\"", "\\\\\"", [{return, list}, global])`  expression based on what I said in the answer.